# MongoDB is not connecting through window server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, google-cloud-platform, mongodb

When I am trying to connect mongodb server which is running on google window server. It is giving error `Network is unreachable`.

I check the firewall port is open for all connection.

mongodb is running

On server if I type url `http://localhost:27017` it is giving output `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.`

But If I try to fetch using IP `http://35.x.x.x:27017/` then it is showing `this site can't be reached`

Comment: To isolate whether the problem is at the application or the network level you can follow the same troubleshooting steps proposed on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455948/how-to-open-https-port-in-google-cloud). Running a port scan will let you know if the port is reachable or being filtered by a firewall (Google firewall or inside the VM). Also use the [netstat command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) to confirm your Mongo service is listening on all the interfaces and not only localhost.

Comment: @Carlos I found a solution. runing mongodb server using command `mongod --bind_ip= 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have found the solution, posting an answer to add visibility.

Mongodb was not listening on all the IP addresses. This was solve by [binding the service to 0.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost).

- For similar cases, you can check the following troubleshooting steps:

  1. Check any internal Firewall configurations on your instance is not blocking connections. Also, try to check any internal setting in your Mongodb.
  2. Try to find out which port and interfaces the Mongodb server is listening on. You can try [netstat command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) options here for Windows.
  3. Run a port scanner like nmap can help to [isolate the problem](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html). To check the port connectivity: nmap -sT -p Port IP

A similar approach is followed in [this other discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455948/how-to-open-https-port-in-google-cloud)